# Create Application Scene in blank OS X Storyboard

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6

I try to transfer an existing cocoa application to make use of the new storyboards for OS X with XCode6 (Beta2).
I added a new blank storyboard file and set it as the main interface of my application.

However, I have no idea how to link my *NSApplication* to this storyboard.

When I start a *new* project using storyboards I see a scene called *application scene*. It includes the Application (NSApplication object), Main Menu, AppDelegate...

How can I add an application object (i.e. an application scene) to a blank storyboard?

Is there something analogous to window controller and view controller objects which can be  dragged on the storyboard?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As a quicker alternative, you could copy the Application Scene from a new project to your existing one:

1. Create a new, empty project with the "Use storyboards" option enabled.
2. In the new project, option-click the storyboard file, select "Open with External Editor".
3. In your favorite text editor, select the Scene node right under "<!--Application-->" and copy it to clipboard.
4. In the project that has a missing Application Scene, repeat step 2.
5. Paste the scene node you just copied at the top of the Scenes node (mind the plural!).
6. Save.

You'll now have an Application Scene in your existing project, which saves a lot of time compared to copying everything over to a new project.

Comment: Worked for me. Create the new project with the same name to avoid having to rename menu items

Comment: Great. No need for an external text editor thou. Just open both the storyboards as source code (right-click selection on storyboard file), do your copy-past stuff, then you can open them again as storyboard and see your scene there

Comment: Are you able to then link the AppDelegate custom object to any of the main window controller items? In my experience, after copying the "Application Scene" from a new project into an existing project's storyboard, I'm able to specify my AppDelegate class (which helps load the App Delegate object) but I can't link to that AppDelegate object in the storyboard with other scenes. It means that the toolbar and menu items all remain unconnected. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Some people at the Apple Developer Forum seem to have the same problem as well: 
[Mac Storyboard and Application Menus](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/232963?tstart=0)

It seems that currently there is no out-of-the-box way of migrating an existing application to use storyboards. That's true at least for XCode6 Beta2.

I ended up creating a new project and transferring my existing code base manually.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is just to copy and paste the objects from a fresh project that had "Use storyboards" checked during creation within XCode.